# how to use multiclass.au1p measure in mlr

Tags: r, auc, mlr, multiclass-classification

I am trying to use multiclass.au1p measure in mlr package. It gave me an error saying

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    Measure multiclass.au1p requires
>   predict type to be: 'prob'!

When I tried to set the predict type to prob then it gave me an error similar to following for any classifier i used

> Error in setPredictType.Learner(learner, predict.type) :    Trying to
>   predict probs, but classif.xgboost.multiclass does not support that!

How can I resolve this?

Following is my code

```
  trainTask <- makeClassifTask(data = no_out_pso,target = "response_grade")

  Clslearn = makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "prob")
  Clslearn = makeMulticlassWrapper(Clslearn, mcw.method = "onevsrest")
  Clslearn = setPredictType(Clslearn, "prob")

  rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3)

  r = resample(Clslearn, trainTask, rdesc, measures = list(mlr::acc, mlr::multiclass.au1p, mlr::multiclass.au1u))

  print(r)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not work with the `makeMulticlassWrapper`, because this does not support probability prediction (at the moment). I get also an error, when I try to set it to `prob` in your code.

Code that works:

```
Clslearn = makeLearner("classif.xgboost", predict.type = "prob")
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 3)
r = resample(Clslearn, iris.task, rdesc, measures = list(mlr::acc, mlr::multiclass.au1p, mlr::multiclass.au1u))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a classifier that supports predicting probabilities. You can get a list with the `listLearners()` function:

```
listLearners(properties = "prob")
```

Comment: hey but when I tried listLearners("classif", properties = c("multiclass", "prob"))[c("class","multiclass","prob") ] xgboost and the other learners i tried, returned true for both mullticlass and prob